# Force a Hyperlink to open in iOS Safari

Tags: ios, email, web, hyperlink, safari

Hi I'm experiencing an issue where users are trying to access a Qualtrics survey via a hyperlink provided to them through email on their mobile devices (iOS). My organization uses Good Technology's managed Email, Calendar, Contacts, Browser, IM, etc... Application suite (Blackberry owns them).

For whatever reason the Good Browser is unable to open the hyperlink natively from email and the Good email suite prevents copying and pasting links out of managed email into native browsers like iOS on safari. I've attached a screenshot of the error below.

Accordingly, I'm wondering if there is some way to prefix a hyperlink so that you can force it to open on the devices native browser in this case safari for iOS. I've created a test survey on Qualtrics that you can use to prefix and I can test. Thanks in advance. https://testsurvey.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_8iWMaM8Uf5fQTXf

[image: Good Browser Error]

Comment: The whole point of the Good suite is to prevent data leakage from the managed environment.  Why would they provide a URL that let the user open links in Safari?  It sounds like you need to raise this with Good or perhaps the survey site is trying to load something from a URL that is blocked by the organisation's firewall or filters.

Comment: Sure, but when the environment doesn't have another survey platform available to it and Qualtrics doesn't support the Good Browser that's an issue. I don't think this is a firewall issue, this looks more like Good's Browser on iOS devices will not open the hyperlink. Moreover, Android users running the Good Suite don't have this issue. It's exclusive to Good+iOS. I've contacted Good and Qualtrics already, wouldn't be here if I hadn't

Comment: Unfortunately, "here" can't help you either since this doesn't appear to be a programming question, but as I said if this were possible then Good would have a big problem that they would need to fix since they are meant to provide a secure environment. See [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: Your saying that prefixing a hyperlink with the appropriate syntax/code to route it to an iOS devices native Safari browser isn't a programming question?

Comment: I wouldn't really consider it a programming question, no, but that is just my opinion.  Others may have a different opinion.